# Changing Text in Javascript From HTML Input Field

Tags: javascript, forms, text, input

So I am setting up Jeopardy game.

For the grid I am using HTML Tables. The first row has generic text right now ("Category 1 Name" for example).

Above the first row there will be another table with an HTML input box where the user can change the category name into whatever they want.

My problem is, I thought I would use `document.getElementById("").innerHTML` etc. to do this but that does not work.

How do I make it so that a user can input text into the form field and that entry changes the text in the table cell (td)?
This is what I have right now for the input field:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Category 1 Name">
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have for the box that I want to change the text:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">Category 1 Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, `getElementById()` only works if your element has an `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this solution be OK for you?:

```js
function setCat1Name() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("cat1")[0].textContent = document.getElementById("myInput").value
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Category 1 Name">
        <button onclick="setCat1Name()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </td>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">Category 1 Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```